# re.search not able to find the regex pattern inside a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file

I have test file(test.txt) as below:

```
`RANGE(vddout,sup)

`RANGE(vddin,sup_p)
```

I would like to modify this file as below:

```
`RANGE(vddout,sup,tol_sup)

`RANGE(vddin,sup_p,tol_sup_p)
```

Here is the code I tried but its not able to find and the replace the pattern using re.search. Could you point out where is the flaw in the code?

```
 with open("test.txt", 'r+') as file :
    for line in file:
        print("line={}".format(line))
        findPattern=re.search(r'(`RANGE\(\w+,(\w+))\)',line)
        if findPattern:
            print("findPattern={}".format(findPattern))
            line=re.sub(r'(`RANGE\(\w+,(\w+))\)',r'\1,tol_\2',line)
```

Comment: You need to escape the literal `(` that you are trying to match.

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything with the line after you perform the substitution.

Comment: thank but that was just a typo during copy paste and editing. I still have same issue after escaping '('

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you aren't writing the file.

Moreover, you are reading each line one by one when you could just be reading the entire file as a string to perform your manipulation. This is both inefficient (as you need to perform `re.sub` multiple times) and more complicated* to code (as you need to create a new string to write to the file).

Finally, you are performing `re.match` *and* `re.sub`. This is unnecessary as `re.sub` will simply do nothing if there is no match; you don't need to check first.

```
In [188]: with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
     ...:     data = f.read()
     ...:     updated = re.sub(r'(`RANGE\(\w+,(\w+))', r'\1,tol_\2', data)
     ...:     f.seek(0)         # Start writing at the beginning of the file
     ...:     f.write(updated)
```

*Note: more complex but not difficult

Comment: Thank you, this is most efficient solution. I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. (you don't have to search first and then replace. You can directly attempt to replace. It only replaces if it matches in the first place)

```
import re

with open("test.txt", 'r+') as file :
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        print(re.sub(r'`RANGE\((\w+),(\w+)\)', r'`RANGE(\1,\2,tol_\2)`', line))
```